# $lookup not printing the answer as expected,showing empty array after joining the two collections

Tags: node.js

Basically I was making a notification api in backend where I am joining 2 collections using lookup. UserInfo collection should show the sendInfo type array in which there should be likes in response if but I am getting sendInfo as empty array.Please help

```
router.get("/notifications", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    //  const id=req.user._id;
    let result = await UserInfo.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          _id: req.user._id
        }
      },

      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "sendlikecoffees",
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "receiverId",
          as: "sendInfo"
        }
      }
    ]);

    if (result) {
      return res.status(200).json({
        Body: result
      });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return res.status(500).json({
      Body: "NETWORK_ERROR"
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant libraries you are using in the tags ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ObjectId.

```
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;

router.get("/notifications", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    //  const id=req.user._id;
    let result = await UserInfo.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          _id: ObjectId(req.user._id)
        }
      },

      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "sendlikecoffees",
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "receiverId",
          as: "sendInfo"
        }
      }
    ]);

    if (result) {
      return res.status(200).json({
        Body: result
      });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return res.status(500).json({
      Body: "NETWORK_ERROR"
    });
  }
});
```